# Can this RVDT be wired in a 3-Wire RVDT Configuration

Tags: signal

Hello I have an RVDT and was wondering if it can be wired in a 3-Wire configuration. [Here](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Measurement-Specialties/02560231-000/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvWgbUE6GM3Of5F1rm2Sxx6mFsjzhBzhF0%3D) is the RVDT I have. I thought by combining the blue and green wires it would be the same as a 3-Wire.

Answer (score 0):

OK. That would reduce a 6 wire to a 5 wire transducer. The common point then becomes the secondary twisted pair coaxial shield.

If  the  transducer is  located  in  an  extremely  noisy  environment,  the primary  leads  should  be  shielded separately from the secondary leads. It is undesirable to have the primary and secondary leads within the same  shield  as  this  may  cause  detrimental  coupling  between  them.  Using multiple RVDT's can have crosstalk with heterodyning beat frequency, so they must be in sync and separately shielded inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You should either tie the blue and black or green and red together. You want the voltages to buck and cancel out at the null point.